# How to Increase my root partition's size. I am dual booting with windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I am using ubuntu 18.04 lts and I am getting a warning that there is low disk space in my root partition. Here is an image of my partitions.
[gparted screenshow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBZc9.jpg).I am really scared to do anything on my own because I think I will mess it up. Can somebody help me?

Comment: you can extended the root partition size with live session of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Comment: You could try to investigate why you have low space. May be something unusual is taking too much space. Look at `baobab` for a grapihcal software or `ncdu` on the command line

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with decreasing the size of /home partition from left side to the right side and after that you can extend the / partition. 
Please before doing that make a backup of your data. There is always a risk resizing of partitions.
Some tools may not allow this operation.